# Docker-compose throws error to connect to credential provider

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, aws-sdk

I am trying to docker-compose my application which throws an error

```
client_1  | CredentialsProviderError: Could not load credentials from any providers
client_1  |     at /abcd/node_modules/@aws-sdk/credential-provider-node/dist-cjs/defaultProvider.js:13:11
client_1  |     at /abcd/node_modules/@smithy/property-provider/dist-cjs/chain.js:11:28
client_1  |     at propagateAslWrapper (/abcd/node_modules/async-listener/index.js:504:23)
client_1  |     at proxyWrapper (/abcd/node_modules/async-listener/index.js:513:29)
client_1  |     at /abcd/node_modules/async-listener/index.js:541:70
client_1  |     at /abcd/node_modules/async-listener/glue.js:188:31
client_1  |     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
client_1  |   tryNextLink: false,
client_1  |   '$metadata': { attempts: 1, totalRetryDelay: 0 }
client_1  | }
```

This error is not happening while I am trying to up my application without docker. With `node /src` it is running file and with `docker-compose up client`, it is throwing this error

DockerFile

```
FROM node:18-alpine

# Use bundler cache
ENV NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=/node_modules

# Set up working directory
ENV APP_HOME=/abcd

RUN mkdir $APP_HOME
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

ADD . $APP_HOME
RUN npm install
RUN npm install @aws-sdk/client-cloudwatch-logs
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  client: &env_client
    image: "abcd:latest"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: sh -c "npm run dev" &
    # command: sh -c "node_modules/.bin/pm2-runtime start ecosystem.config.js" & # pm2 cluster implementation
    ports:
      - "3030:3030"
      - "9229:9229"
    env_file: .env
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
      - NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=/node_modules
    volumes:
      - "npm_node_modules:/node_modules"
      - ./:/abcd


volumes:
  npm_node_modules:
  rabbitmq_data:
    driver: local
```

All the .aws credential files are looking good

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

I did changing the .aws file and all, It didn't work